# How many phone numbers can be in one Twilio SMS/MMS application?

Tags: twilio

In the Twilio platform, you can create an "Application" to bundle common configuration details for phone numbers.  From https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/applications:

> An application inside of Twilio is just a set of URLs and other configuration data that tells Twilio how to behave when one of your Twilio numbers receives a call or SMS message.

Is there a limit to how many phone numbers can be joined into a single Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

"TwiML Applications" like the one you mention are designed to be aliases easy to use on a ton of numbers at once, we have a lot of very high volume customers using them on 10,000+ Twilio numbers and probably even a lot more.

In case you need to go beyond those numbers, it's always worth contacting sales as they will be able to increase that for you accordingly while making sure you scale well.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful to know.